# Number of roots of the equation $ax^2+ bx + c = 0$ in $(1,2)$

Tags: roots, quadratics

> Let $a, b, c \in R, a \ne 0$ such that $a$ and $4a + 3b + 2c$ have the same sign. Then the
> number of roots of the equation $ax^2+ bx + c = 0$ that lie(s) in $(1,2)$ is(are)?

I began by writing that $4a^2+3ab+2ac>0$. I tried finding the sign of $f(1)\cdot f(2)$ to use this condition and Bolzano's theorem. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to proceed.

Comment: Use Sturm's theorem. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem#The_theorem

Comment: @user3257842 thanks, I didn't know this theorem. Please let me know if there's any mistake in my understanding: first, we find the Sturm sequence by finding the negative remainders of the polynomial when divided by its derivatives. Now we substitute two values(the range extrema) and find the difference of the number of sign changes in each, and this gives us the number of roots.

Comment: I tried this way and turns out I need to find the signs of $a+b+c$ and $\frac{b^2}{4a}-c$, which is not obvious to me

Comment: Let $a \gt 0 $, therefore ,$4a + 3b + 2c \gt 0$ .
Now $4a +3b + 2c = f(2) + (b+c)$ 
Therefore , $f(2) +(b+c) \gt 0$ .

Also , $f(1) = a +b+c$ . Therefore, $f(2) + f(1) - a \gt 0 $, and hence , $f(1) +f(2) \gt a $. This is only possible when the equation has atleast one root in (1,2)

Comment: $f(1)+f(2)>a\implies f(1)+f(2)>0$ which means at least one of $f(1),f(2)$ is greater than zero.  How did you conclude that there exists at least one root from here? @Sukhoi234

Comment: Good luck on jee <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can say that if the number of the roots lying in $(1,2)$ is $2$, then the axis of symmetry of the parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$ lies in $(1,2)$.

Therefore, one can say that if the axis of symmetry of the parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$ does not lie in $(1,2)$, then the number of the roots lying in $(1,2)$ is not $2$.

One has
$$0\lt \frac{2a(4a+3b+2c)}{4a^2}\leqslant \frac{8a^2+6ab+b^2}{4a^2}=\bigg(1-\bigg(-\frac{b}{2a}\bigg)\bigg)\bigg(2-\bigg(-\frac{b}{2a}\bigg)\bigg)$$
i.e.
$$\bigg(1-\bigg(-\frac{b}{2a}\bigg)\bigg)\bigg(2-\bigg(-\frac{b}{2a}\bigg)\bigg)\gt 0$$
which means that the axis of symmetry of the parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$ does not lie in $(1,2)$.

Therefore, one can say that the number of the roots lying in $(1,2)$ is not $2$.

If $a=1,b=1$ and $c=-1$ satisfying $a(4a+3b+2c)\gt 0$, then the number of roots lying in $(1,2)$ is $0$.

If $a=1,b=1$ and $c=-3$ satisfying $a(4a+3b+2c)\gt 0$, then the number of roots lying in $(1,2)$ is $1$.

---

**Added** :

If $a(4a+3b+2c)\gt 0$ and $b^2-4ac=0$, then the number of the roots lying in $(1,2)$ is $0$.

Under $a(4a+3b+2c)\gt 0$ and $b^2-4ac\gt 0$, the number of the roots lying in $(1,2)$ is
$$\begin{cases}0&\text{if $\ (a+b+c)(4a+2b+c)\geqslant 0$}
\\\\ 1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

This can be seen by noting that the axis of symmetry of the parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$ does not lie in $(1,2)$ and that $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is monotone on $(1,2)$.

Comment: The values you have given in your second example do not satisfy the initial conditions. Also, can you elaborate a bit on the first step?

Comment: @DatBoi : I've just added some explanations. If $a=1, b=1$ and $c=-3$, then $a(4a+3b+2c)\gt 0$ holds.

Comment: Ah, my bad! Thanks for the details. So the number of roots is indeed dependant on $a,b,c$(i.e. on some other constraint)

Comment: @DatBoi : I've got the constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from $4a^2+3ab+2ac=a(4a+3b+2c)>0$.

Then we have

$8a^2+6ab+4ac>0$

### Case 1: $-\frac{b}{2a}<2$

$\implies 8a^2+6ab+b^2 > b^2-4ac$

$\implies \frac{8a^2+6ab+b^2}{4a^2} > \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$ , since $a^2 > 0, a \in \mathcal{R} \wedge a \neq 0$

$\implies 2+\frac{3b}{2a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2} > \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$

$\implies (1+\frac{b}{2a})(2+\frac{b}{2a}) > \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$

$\implies (2+\frac{b}{2a})(2+\frac{b}{2a}) > (1+\frac{b}{2a})(2+\frac{b}{2a}) > \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$, since $2+\frac{b}{2a}>0$

$\implies (2+\frac{b}{2a})^2 > \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$

$\implies (2+\frac{b}{2a})^2 - \left(\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)^2 > 0$

$\implies \left(2+\frac{b}{2a}+\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)\left(2+\frac{b}{2a}-\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right) > 0$

$\implies \left(-2-\frac{b}{2a}-\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)\left(-2-\frac{b}{2a}+\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right) > 0$

$\implies \left(-\frac{b}{2a}-\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}-2\right)\left(-\frac{b}{2a}+\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}-2\right) > 0$

$\implies -\frac{b}{2a}\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} > 2$ (in which case there is no root in between 1 and 2,since both roots > 2)

OR $\;\;-\frac{b}{2a}\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} < 2$, in which case both the roots are less than 2. For the second case we need further analysis, can you take it from here?

Also, notice that $f(1)-(b+c)=a$ and $f(2)+(b+c)=4a+3b+2c$ have the same sign.

### Case 2: $-\frac{b}{2a}\geq 2$

The roots are $-\frac{b}{2a}\pm\sqrt{(\frac{b}{2a})^2-\frac{c}{a}}$, where the larger root $\geq$ 2, so that we may have at most one (the smaller) root in $(1,2)$, but it needs further analysis.

Comment: I dont think the new inequality you introduced in the 5th implies step is true. It should be dependant on $\frac{b}{2a}$

Comment: Take a look at [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xfbdvgvrbb) and notice how the inequality varies

Comment: of course, it is. The problem is its multiplied again. For example, let $b/2a=-5$ so $2+b/2a=-3$ and $1+b/2a=-4$. Obviously $-3>-4$ but $-3*-3<-3*-4$

Comment: No worries! The manipulation of inequalities was great! Looking forward to your corrected answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I took another approach with this after looking for a direct approach to working with the quadratic polynomial.  We can define a quantity $ \ \Phi \ = \ \frac{4a + 3b + 2c}{a} \ \ , $ so that $ \ \Phi \ > \ 0 \ $ when both $ \ a \ $ and $ \ 4a + 3b + 2c \ $ have the same sign, and $ \ \Phi \ < \ 0 \ $ when they have opposite signs.  For the polynomial $ \ ax^2 + bx + c \ $ with zeroes $ \ r \ $ and $ \ s \ \ , $ we have
$$   \Phi \ \ = \ \ 4 \ + \ \frac{ 3b }{a} \ + \ \frac{2c}{a} \ \ = \ \ 4 \  - \ 3·(r + s) \ + \ 2·rs \ \ . $$

We can then plot $ \ \Phi \ $ in the " $ rs-$plane".  The boundary between regions of positive [green] and negative [red] values of $ \ \Phi \ $ is the translated rectangular hyperbola $ \ 2rs \ - \ 3r \ - \ 3s \ + \ 4 \ = \ 0 \ \  $ centered on $ \ \left(\frac32 \ , \ \frac32 \right) \ $ and with asymptotes $ \ r \ = \ \frac32 \ \ , \ \ s \ = \ \frac32 \ \ $ (which has more than a little bearing on our problem).  Since $ \ \Phi \ $ is independent of the ordering/designation of the two zeroes, we only need to consider the portion of the graph on or "above" the blue diagonal line.

We find that all pairs of zeroes $ \ 1 \ < \ r \ , \ s \ < \ 2 \ \ $ are contained within the red square, which lies entirely within the region $ \ \Phi \ < \ 0 \ \ . $  (The corners of the square tangent to the hyperbola correspond to the binomial-squares $ \ ( x - 1 )^2 \ $ and $ \ ( x - 2 )^2 \ \ . \ ) $  We can obtain this separately from
$$    1 \ < \ r \ , \ s \ < \ 2  \  \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2 \ < \ r + s \ < \ 4 \ \ , \ \ 1 \ < \ r·s \ < \ 4 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 6 \ < \ 4 \ + \ 2·r·s \ < \ 12 \ \ , \ \ -12 \ < \ -3·(r + s) \ < \ -6 \ \  \Rightarrow \ \ -6 \ < \ \Phi \ < \ 0 \ \ . $$
So we *are* able to say that when **both** zeroes of the quadratic polynomial lie in $ \ (1 \ , \ 2 ) \ \ , \ a \ $ and $ \ 4a + 3b + 2c \ $ have **opposite signs** . The contrapositive then holds (as observed in the analyses by **Sandipan Dey** and by **mathlove**
) :  if $ \ \Phi \ > \ 0 \ \ , $ both zeroes cannot fall within that interval.

Otherwise, $ \ \Phi \ $ can tell  us only a little more about the zeroes.  The yellow bands on the graph indicate the situation for only one zero being found in $ \ (1 \ , \ 2 ) \ \ . $  Because the asymptotes bisect these bands, $ \ \Phi \ $ may be positive or negative for that case; further information is needed to resolve the sign of this quantity.  Otherwise, we can say somewhat broadly that

•  $ \ \Phi \ > \ 0 \ $ when  $ \  r  \ , \  s  \ > \ 2 \ \ $ or $ \ \  r  \ , \  s  \ < \ 1 \ \ ; $

•  $ \ \Phi \ < \ 0 \ $ when one zero is greater than $ \  2 \ $ and the other is less than $ \  1 \ \ . $

So $ \ \Phi \ $ can have either sign even when there are **no zeroes** within $ \ ( 1 \ , \ 2) \ \ . $  More precise investigation is needed if either zero is close to the boundary hyperbola.